# Checkboxes are checked but they have no initial value on page reload

Tags: angular, typescript, forms, checkbox

The current setup works find when i check/uncheck boxes and submit to server.

however, when the page reloads or when i go to edit, the page loads fine and the checkbox is checking the right entries like this...

[image]

The problem here is when i click submit without touching any values, the array is submitted empty `permission_ids: []`, they need to be clicked again in order to fire the `OnChange()` and i can't do this automatically when i page loads since i'm new to Angular

So the issue here as i understand, that the checkboxes are checked but the value of the form isn't updated.

here are the code

Template

```
<h4>Permissions</h4>
            <div class="form-group row p-t-20">
              <div class="col-sm-4">
                <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox" *ngFor="let perm of permissions; let i=index">                
                  <input
                    type="checkbox"
                    class="custom-control-input"
                    id="permission_{{perm.id}}"
                    [value]="perm.id"
                    (change)="onPermissionCheckboxChange($event)"
                    [checked]="permissionExists(perm.id)">
                  <label
                    class="custom-control-label"
                    for="permission_{{perm.id}}">
                    {{ perm.name }}
                  </label>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
```

TS

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, FormArray, FormControl, Validators  } from "@angular/forms";
import { NotificationService } from "../../notification/notification.service";
import { PermissionsService } from "../../permissions/permissions.service";
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
import { environment } from "../../../../environments/environment";
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from "@angular/router";
import { RolesService } from "../roles.service";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-edit-role',
  templateUrl: './edit-role.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./edit-role.component.css']
})
export class EditRoleComponent implements OnInit {
  isLoading: boolean = false;
  roleId: number = +this.route.snapshot.params['id']
  roleObj: any = {};
  haveRole: any = true;
  roles: any;
  role: any;

  permissions: any;

  form: FormGroup;

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
    private router: Router,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private fb: FormBuilder,
    private notificationService: NotificationService,
    private rolesService: RolesService,
    private permissionsService: PermissionsService
  ) {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      role: new FormGroup({
        name: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
        permission_ids: this.fb.array([])
      })
    })
  }

  permissionExists(id: number) {
    return this.role.permissions.find(function(el: any){ return el.id === id }) !== undefined;
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.rolesService.getRoles().subscribe(response => {

    this.roles = response.body;
    this.role = this.roles.find((el: any) =>  el.id === this.roleId)

    //console.log(this.role);
    this.isLoading = false;
    this.form.patchValue({
      'role': {
        'name': this.role.name
      }
    });
    },
    error => {
      this.isLoading = false;
      this.notificationService.showNotification(
        error.error.title,
        error.error.details,
        'error'
      );
    })

    
    this.permissionsService.getPermissions().subscribe(response => {

      this.permissions = response.body;
      this.isLoading = false;
    },
    error => {
      this.isLoading = false;
      // console.log(error.error);
      this.notificationService.showNotification(
        error.error.title,
        error.error.details,
        'error'
      );
    })
  }


  onPermissionCheckboxChange(e: any) {
    const checkArray: FormArray = this.form.get('role.permission_ids') as FormArray;
if (e.target.checked) {
      checkArray.push(new FormControl(e.target.value));
    } else {
      let i: number = 0;
      checkArray.controls.forEach((item: any) => {
        if (item.value == e.target.value) {
          checkArray.removeAt(i);
          return;
        }
        i++;
      });
    }
  }

  onSubmit() {
    this.roleObj.role = this.form.value.role
    console.log(this.roleObj)
  }
}
```

Excuse my poor code but I'm still learning angular as i'm mainly Ruby on Rails developer

Comment: You do `this.form.patchValue` in `ngOnInit` to patch the name, why don't you do the same with permissions? This way the form would be updated and the template won't need this `[checked]="permissionExists(perm.id)"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amir, is a bit confused your code. (futhermore your'e mixins FormBuilder and the constructor of FormControl)

First think in object, after create the Form. I imagine your "role" is like, e.g.

```
{
  name:'name',
  permissions:[1,3]
}
```

And your permissions and array like

```
[{id:1,name:"Can create category"},{id:2,name:"Can read category}...]
```

A input type "checkbox" in Angular only has two values: true or false, So if you use a FormArray its value will be e.g.[true,false,true,false,false]

So one approach can be create a FormGroup like

```
  form = new FormGroup({
    name: new FormControl(this.role.name, [Validators.required]),
    permissions: new FormArray(
      this.permissions.map(
        x => new FormControl(this.role.permissions.find(p => p == x.id) != null)
      )
    )
  });
```

To manage, create a getter rolePermision that return the formArray

```
get rolePermision()
{
    return this.form.get('permissions') as FormArray
}
```

And an html like

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
   <input formControlName="name">
   <div formArrayName="permissions">
     <div *ngFor="let control of rolePermision.controls;let i=index">
      <input 
            [formControlName]="i" type="checkbox">{{permissions[i].name}}
            </div>
   </div>
</form>
```

Then, after you make submit

```
submit(form: FormGroup) {
    if (form.valid) {
      const data = {
        name: this.form.value.name,
        permisions: this.permissions
          .filter((x, index) => form.value.permissions[index])
          .map(x => x.id)
      };
      ...use data to send to your service..
    }
  }
```

The another approach is to has a formGroup with two formControls, one of them store an array

```
  form = new FormGroup({
    name: new FormControl(this.role.name, [Validators.required]),
    permissions:new FormControl(this.role.permissions)
  })
```

And use a [ngModel] and (ngModelChange)

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
  <input formControlName="name">
  <div *ngFor="let permision of permissions">
    <input type="checkbox" [ngModel]="form.get('permissions')?.value && form.get('permissions').value.indexOf(permision.id)>=0"
    [ngModelOptions]="{standalone:true}"
    (ngModelChange)="change(permision.id,$event)"
    >{{permision.name}}
    </div>
  
</form>
```

The function change like

```
  change(id: any, checked: boolean) {
    const oldValue = this.form.value.permissions;
    const permissions = checked
      ? this.permissions.filter(
          x => (oldValue && oldValue.indexOf(x.id) >= 0) || x.id == id
        )
      : this.permissions.filter(
          x => oldValue && oldValue.indexOf(x.id) >= 0 && x.id != id
        );

    this.form
      .get('permissions')
      .setValue(permissions.length > 0 ? permissions.map(x => x.id) : null);
  }
```

You can get the two approach in [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-srfqjo?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: Thanks @Eliseo for the answer, it worked fine (The first approach) but now i have a little issue which is, i can't populate the roles and permissions from the server, something i can't understand that has to do with lifecycle hooks, I opened a question related to it, kindly check it :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67963800/i-cant-dynamically-populate-form-with-values-on-reload and thank you very much :)