# I can't dynamically populate form with values on reload

Tags: angular, typescript, forms

This code works fine, the template part is ok, the issue here is that the template get populated just fine with this static values (Roles, permissions and managers)

but once i call the API and get the new values and change the roles object or permissions or managers, the form read the initial empty values

maybe it has something to so with subscription ? subject ? i'm not sure since i'm new to Angular

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, FormArray, FormControl, Validators  } from "@angular/forms";
import { ManagersService } from "../../managers/managers.service";
import { NotificationService } from "../../notification/notification.service";
import { PermissionsService } from "../../permissions/permissions.service";
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
import { environment } from "../../../../environments/environment";
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from "@angular/router";
import { RolesService } from "../roles.service";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-edit-role',
  templateUrl: './edit-role.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./edit-role.component.css']
})
export class EditRoleComponent implements OnInit {
  isLoading: boolean = false;
  roleId: number = +this.route.snapshot.params['id']
  roles: any;
  originalRole: any = {};
  role = { name: '', permissions: [], managers: [] };
  // permissions: any = {};
  // roles: any = {};
  
  permissions = [
    { id: 1, name: 'Can create category' },
    { id: 2, name: 'Can read category' },
    { id: 3, name: 'Can update category' },
    { id: 4, name: 'Can destroy category' }
  ];
  managers = [
    { id: 1, name: 'Amir' },
    { id: 2, name: 'Asmaa' },
  ];    
  
    
  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
    private router: Router,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private fb: FormBuilder,   
    private notificationService: NotificationService,
    private rolesService: RolesService,
    private managersService: ManagersService,
    private permissionsService: PermissionsService
  ) { 
  } 
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.rolesService.getRoles().subscribe(response => {
this.roles = response.body;
    this.originalRole = this.roles.find((el: any) =>  el.id === this.roleId)
    // this.permissions = this.originalRole.permissions;

    this.form.patchValue({
      'role': {
        'name': this.originalRole.name,
        'permissions': this.originalRole.permissions.map(a => a.id),
        'managers': this.originalRole.managers.map(a => a.id)
      }
    });

    console.log(this.role);
    this.isLoading = false;
    },
    error => {
      this.isLoading = false;
      this.notificationService.showNotification(
        error.error.title,
        error.error.details,
        'error'
      );
    })
  }

  form = new FormGroup({
    role: new FormGroup({
      name: new FormControl(this.role.name, [Validators.required]),
      permissions: new FormArray(
        this.permissions.map(
          x => new FormControl(this.role.permissions.find(p => p == x.id) != null)
        )
      ),
      managers: new FormArray(
        this.managers.map(
          x => new FormControl(this.role.managers.find(p => p == x.id) != null)
        )
      )
    })
  });
  get name() {
    return this.form.get('role.name') as FormArray;
  }
get rolePermisions() {
    return this.form.get('role.permissions') as FormArray;
  }
  get roleManagers() {
    return this.form.get('role.managers') as FormArray;
  }
  submit(form: FormGroup) {
    if (form.valid) {
      const data = {
        role: {
          name: this.form.value.role.name,
          permisions: this.permissions
            .filter((x, index) => form.value.role.permissions[index])
            .map(x => x.id),
          managers: this.managers
            .filter((x, index) => form.value.role.managers[index])
            .map(x => x.id)
        }
      };
      console.log(data);
    }
  }
}
```

As shown above, it's ok to use the static permissions array, but when i assign the newly fetched array to the permissions variable (The commented out lines), i still get the empty one, am i missing something here to re-populate the values correctly ?

**UPDATE**

I'm not sure if you guys understood me or not
in a simpler way

```
myRole: any = [];

  
  ngOnInit(): void {           
    this.rolesService.getRoles().subscribe(response => {
  
      let roles = response.body;
      let role = roles.find((el: any) =>  el.id === this.roleId)
      console.log(role)
      // This logs the role fine
      
      // Now setting the above variable
      this.myRole = role
    })

    console.log(this.myRole)
    // This NEVER want to be set, i know i'm missing something simple but i can't get it
  }
```

Comment: Can you please simulate this issue in stackbliz so that it is easy to debug ?

Comment: You are initializing your form controls for `permissions` and `managers` with Boolean default values, but are then setting them to number values in the `patchValue` call. This may give you a hint as to where the problem could be.

Comment: Also, be careful when using `ActivatedRoute.snapshot`. Angular is allowed to (and usually does) reuse your component when the only change in the URL is the current route's parameter values, and your component will not be notified of these changes. It is better to subscribe to `ActivatedRoute.paramMap` instead. See [here](https://angular.io/guide/router-tutorial-toh#observable-parammap-and-component-reuse)

Comment: I have added small update with the real issue i'm having

Answer (score 0):

You has a static values, but you has a service that return roles and permisions.

```
//your service, I imagine more or less 
//I use an unique service, perhafs you use two services

getPermissions(){
   return httpClient.get("yoururl/api/permissions");
}
getManagers(){
   return httpClient.get("yoururl/api/managgers");
}
getRole(id){ //(*)
   return httpClient.get("yoururl/api/role/"+id);
}

//(*) from your another question, if you has a function that return all the roles 
//you can has in your service a "cache" of roles

import {of} from 'rxjs'
import {tap,map} from 'rxjs/operators'
allRoles:any[]
getRole(id){ //(*)
   if (this.allRoles) //If exist, use "of" rxjs operator to return an observable of role
      return of(this.allRoles.find(x=>x.id==id)

   //else get all roles
   return httpClient.get("yoururl/api/getAllRoles").pipe(
      tap(res=>this.allRoles=res), //<--use tap to store in the variable the result
      map(res=>res.find(x=>x.id==id))  //<--use map to return only the role with id
   )
}
//be careful!!!!, if we "cache" the allRoles, rememeber after you edit a role
//"clean" de caché using:
        this.allRoles=null
//else you always received the caché roles

//similar, create a new variables "permisions" and "managers" to "cache"
//so the functions becomes
permisions:any[];
managers:any[];

getPermissions(){
   if (this.permisions)
       return of(this.permisions);
   return httpClient.get("yoururl/api/permissions").pipe(
      tap(res=>this.permisions=res));
}

//and
getManagers(){
   if (this.managers)
       return of(this.managers);
   return httpClient.get("yoururl/api/managgers").pipe(
       tap(res=>this.managers=res))
   )
}
```

(*) the tap operator simple received the value to make "something" with the response- generally it's used to "log" or to "cache"

You see that, to create the FormGroup you need get the value of "role", "permissions" and "managers".

So we are going to do **all** in ngOnInit. How get all observables? using forkJoin (yes another rxjs operator)

If we has in a variable "id" the role we can make

```
ngOnInit()
{
   forkJoin([this.roleService.getPermissions(),
            this.roleService.getManagers(),
            this.rolesService.getRole(id)]).subscribe(
              ([permisions,managers,role]:[any[],any[],any])=>{
                  this.permisions=permisions;
                  this.managers=managers;
                  this.role=role;
                  ..here we call to a funciton to create the formGroup..
              })
            )
}
```

(*)forkjoin create an observable that call in parallel all the "calls", when finished with all return the result -use only if the calls are independients

Well, we has not the "id" (because we get it from the params) so, from the [docs](https://angular.io/guide/router#accessing-query-parameters-and-fragments) we

```
ngOnInit(){
   this.activatedRoute.paramMap.pipe(
     switchMap(params => {
      const id=Number(params.get('id'));
      //here we has the "id"
      return forkJoin([this.roleService.getPermissions(),
                this.roleService.getManagers(),
                this.rolesService.getRole(id)]
    }).subscribe(([permisions,managers,role]:[any[],any[],any])=>{
         ....
       })
  );
}
```

(*) switchmap "reemplace" an observable by another one

Comment: Thanks @Eliseo for your effort, but i have added very small updates simplifying my little issue